# Insertar 'N' veces de registros PHP AJAX MYSQL

Tags: php, ajax, variables, post, insert

estuve buscando una manera de generar una lista con información dependiendo de 2 variables, encontré un ejemplo ([Link](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/10/insert-dynamic-multi-select-box-data-using-jquery-ajax-php.html)) y me pareció interesante.
El problema es que al insertar los datos seleccionados este los inserta en la `Base de Datos` como un mismo registro.

Ejemplo selección:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se registra en la `Base de Datos`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo queria es que en vez de que me mande todo a un mismo registro lo divida en varios dependiendo la cantidad de información que se selecciono.

Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer un `console.log()` a lo enviado por POST me manda esta cadena:

> country=USA&state=New%20York&city=New%20York%20city&city=Buffalo&city=Rochester&hidden_city=New%20York%20city%2CBuffalo%2CRochester

espero haberme explicado.

Base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Conexion:

```html
<?php
//database_connection.php
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");
?>
```

index.php

```html
<?php
//index.php

include('database_connection.php');

$country = '';

$query = "
 SELECT country FROM country_state_city GROUP BY country ORDER BY country ASC
";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $country .= '<option value="'.$row["country"].'">'.$row["country"].'</option>';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Insert Dynamic Multi Select Box Data using Jquery Ajax PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.lwMultiSelect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.lwMultiSelect.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Insert Dynamic Multi Select Box Data using Jquery Ajax PHP</h2><br /><br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_data">
    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control action">
     <option value="">Select Country</option>
     <?php echo $country; ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control action">
     <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="city" id="city" multiple class="form-control">
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_city" id="hidden_city" />
    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="action" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script src="prueba.js"></script>
```

prueba.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#city').lwMultiSelect();

    $('.action').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            var query = $(this).val();
            var result = '';
            if(action == 'country')
            {
                result = 'state';
            }
            else
            {
                result = 'city';
            }
            $.ajax({
                url:'fetch.php',
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action, query:query},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#'+result).html(data);
                    if(result == 'city')
                    {
                        $('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });

    $('#insert_data').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#country').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select Country");
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#state').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select State");
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#city').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select City");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#hidden_city').val($('#city').val());
            $('#action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(form_data);
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetch.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:form_data,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#action').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    if(data == 'done')
                    {
                        $('#city').html('');
                        $('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
                        $('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').removeAll();
                        $('#insert_data')[0].reset();
                        alert('Data Inserted');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

fetch.php

```html
<?php
//fetch.php

//Combobox
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
 include('database_connection.php');

 $output = '';
    //Combobox Pais
 if($_POST["action"] == 'country')
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT state FROM country_state_city 
  WHERE country = :country 
  GROUP BY state
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':country'  => $_POST["query"]
   )
  );
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  $output .= '<option value="">Select State</option>';
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["state"].'">'.$row["state"].'</option>';
  }
 }

 //Combobox Estado
 if($_POST["action"] == 'state')
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT city FROM country_state_city 
  WHERE state = :state
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':state'  => $_POST["query"]
   )
  );
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["city"].'">'.$row["city"].'</option>';
  }


 }
 echo $output;
}


// Para insertar
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
    include('database_connection.php');
    $query = "
 INSERT INTO country_state_city_form_data (country, state, city) 
 VALUES(:country, :state, :city)
 ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':country'  => $_POST['country'],
            ':state'  => $_POST['state'],
            ':city'   => $_POST['hidden_city']
        )
    );
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'done';
    }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estimado, tal como te comento cristian, puedes usar explode(), para cortar las ciudades, en el codigo para insertar prueba con esto:

```
// Para insertar
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{

    $ciudades = explode(",",$_POST["hidden_city"]);

    foreach ($ciudades as &$valor) {

      include('database_connection.php');
      $query = "INSERT INTO country_state_city_form_data (country, state, city)VALUES(:country, :state, :city)";
      $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
      $statement->execute(
         array(
             ':country'     =>  $_POST['country'],
             ':state'       =>  $_POST['state'],
             ':city'        =>  $valor
         )
       );
       $result = $statement->fetchAll();

       if(isset($result))
       {
          echo 'done';
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me funciono este método, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Modifica el select de ciudades a `<select name="city[]" id="city" multiple class="form-control">` en index, para que te permita leer todos los datos.

En tu archivo fetch colocarás un ciclo, en el `if` del post, para leer las ciudades, quedando así:

```
// Para insertar
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
    include('database_connection.php'); 
    $cities = $_POST["city"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO country_state_city_form_data (country, state, city) 
      VALUES";

    for($i=0;$i<count($cities);$i++)
    {
      $query .= "(".$_POST['country'].", ".$_POST['state'].", ".$cities[$i].")";

      if($i<count($cities)-1)
        $query .= ",";
    }

    $query .= ";";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'done';
    }

}
```

Otra opción sin modificar el select es haciendo un corte por "," a las ciudades:

```
// Para insertar
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
    include('database_connection.php'); 
    $cities = explode(",",$_POST["hidden_city"]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO country_state_city_form_data (country, state, city) 
      VALUES";

    for($i=0;$i<count($cities);$i++)
    {
      $query .= "(".$_POST['country'].", ".$_POST['state'].", ".$cities[$i].")";

      if($i<count($cities)-1)
        $query .= ",";
    }

    $query .= ";";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'done';
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, intente de ambas formas y me aparece el mensaje de que se insertaron pero no inserta nada en la Base de datos.

Comment: Checa que contiene el `$result` con `print_r($result);`

Comment: Eso en que parte se pondría?

Comment: En lugar de echo

Comment: Lo intente pero no me imprimia nada mas que el string del post. Igualmente me funciono el codigo de Eduardo, gracias igualmente por el tiempo.