# Obtener dato por medio de POST a PHP desde una consulta SQL MYSQL

Tags: php, ajax, post, combobox

**

Hola buen dia, quería saber como puedo obtener un valor de una consulta por medio de post para enviarlo a un php.

Lo que pasa es que en el código de ejemplo que seguí ([Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183690/insertar-n-veces-de-registros-php-ajax-mysql)) solo manda 3 datos de diferentes `combobox`y ocupo una 4ta variable para poder completar una clausula `WHERE` de una consulta Mysql.

Dejo imágenes ilustrativas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento mandar de nuevo los mismos datos no me inserta, pero si solo cambio el maestro, selecciono la misma materia y alumno si me inserta ya que me faltaría comparar que el `idmateria` no exista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor que necesito obtener es el `idmateria` que lo obtengo junto con otros valores en la consulta en `docente_alumno.php`, pero en el `value` del `combobox` puse `iddocente` ya que lo necesito para la clausula del `combobox` materia.

Algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`FROM notas n
inner join alumno_cuatrimestre_materia a
on n.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia = a.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia
WHERE (n.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia =:alumno AND iddocente_materia =:materia )OR (n.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia =:alumno and idmateria = :IDMATERIA);
```

No se si me di a entender, intente poniendo un `combobox` oculto pero no me lo mando al php.

Codigo:

docente_alumno.php

```html
<?php
include_once '../funciones/Sesiones.php';
if (!($_SESSION['tipo'] == 1)){
    header("Location:home.php");
}else{
    include_once '../funciones/Conexion2.php';
    $docente = '';
    //Consulta donde obtengo  el nombre del maestro y su iddocente, iddocente_materia y el idmateria (este ultimo lo ocupo enviar para la clausula where)
    try{
        $query = "
 SELECT concat(p.nombre,' ', p.apellido_p,' ', p.apellido_m) as Nombre, dm.iddocente, iddocente_materia, idmateria FROM docente d
    inner join persona p on d.idpersona = p.idpersona
    inner join docente_materia dm on d.iddocente = dm.iddocente
    where d.idpersona = p.idpersona and dm.estatus = 1 group by p.idpersona ORDER BY Nombre ASC
";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row) {
            $docente .= '<option value="'.$row["iddocente"].'">'.$row["Nombre"].'</option>';
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    include_once 'header.php';
    include_once 'barra.php';
    include_once 'navegacion.php';
    ?>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1 style="text-align: center">
                Asignar Alumnos
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Cargar alumno</h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                title="Collapse">
                            <i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                        <form method="post" id="insert_data">
                            <select name="docente" id="docente" class="form-control action" required>
                                <option value="">- Selecciona un docente -</option>
                                <?php echo $docente; ?>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                            <select name="materia" id="materia" class="form-control action" required>
                                <option value="">- Selecciona una materia -</option>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                            <select name="alumno" id="alumno" multiple class="form-control" required>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_alumno" id="hidden_alumno" />
                            <button type="submit" name="insert" id="action" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Cargar alumnos</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancelar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i> Cancelar</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
    ?>
    <script src="js/insertar-docente-alumno.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

insertar-docente-alumno.js

```js
function init(){

    docenteAlumno();

    $("#cancelar").on('click',function () {
        window.location.href="listado-docente-alumno.php";
    });

    $("#docente-cancelar").on('click',function () {
        history.go(-1)
    });
}


function docenteAlumno(){
    $('#alumno').lwMultiSelect({
        addAllText:'Agregar todos',
        removeAllText:'Limpiar',
        selectedLabel:'Seleccionados',
    });

    $('.action').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            var query = $(this).val();
            var result = '';
            if(action == 'docente')
            {
                result = 'materia';
            }
            else
            {
                result = 'alumno';
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '../funciones/modelo-docente-alumno.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{action:action, query:query},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#'+result).html(data);
                    if(result == 'alumno')
                    {
                        $('#alumno').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });

    $('#insert_data').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //Alertas en caso de que un combobox no se seleccione (no funciona porque use el atributo required en los combobox)
        if($('#docente').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select docente");
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#materia').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select materia");
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#alumno').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select alumno");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Aqui envia al php
            $('#hidden_alumno').val($('#alumno').val());
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: '../funciones/modelo-docente-alumno.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:form_data,
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data == 'done') {
                        $('#alumno').html('');
                        $('#alumno').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
                        $('#alumno').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').removeAll();
                        $('#insert_data')[0].reset();
                        alert('Data Inserted');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

init();
```

modelo-docente-alumno.php

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    include_once 'Conexion2.php';
    $output = '';


    //Si el combobox de docente esta seleccionado
    if($_POST["action"] == 'docente')
    {
        //Ejecuta consulta sql donde obtiene X materias dependiendo del id del docente capturado en el combobox docente.
        $query = "
        select nombre, dm.* from materia m
        inner join docente_materia dm on m.idmateria = dm.idmateria
        inner join docente d on dm.iddocente = d.iddocente
        where dm.iddocente = :docente and dm.estatus = 1
        group by nombre
  ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':docente'  => $_POST["query"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $output .= '<option value="">- Selecciona una materia -</option>';
        //Rellena el combobox con X opciones dependiendo el resultado de la consulta a materias
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row["iddocente_materia"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
        }
    }

    //Si el combobox de materia esta seleccionado
    if($_POST["action"] == 'materia')
    {
        //Ejecuta consulta sql donde obtiene X alumnos dependiendo del id de la tabla docente_materia capturado en el combobox materia.
        $query = "
  select concat(p.nombre,' ', p.apellido_p,' ', p.apellido_m) as Nombre, idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia from alumno_cuatrimestre_materia acm
        inner join alumno_cuatrimestre a on acm.idalumno_cuatrimestre = a.idalumno_cuatrimestre
        inner join alumno a2 on a.idalumno = a2.idalumno
        inner join persona p on a2.idpersona = p.idpersona
        inner join docente_materia dm on dm.idmateria = acm.idmateria
        where acm.estatus = 1 and dm.iddocente_materia = :materia
  ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':materia'  => $_POST["query"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        //Rellena el combobox con X opciones dependiendo el resultado de la consulta a alumno_cuatrimestre_materia
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row["idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia"].'">'.$row["Nombre"].'</option>';
        }


    }
    echo $output;
}

// Para insertar
if(isset($_POST['docente']))
{
    include_once 'Conexion2.php';
    //separa la cadena enviada delimitandola hasta la ',' del input hidden_alumno
    $ciudades = explode(",",$_POST["hidden_alumno"]);
    //foreach para dividir la cadena POST
    foreach ($ciudades as &$valor) {
        //Consulta sql para verificar si alguno de los alumnos seleccionados existe en la tabla notas, de ser asi no inserta ninguno.
        $sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM notas n
                              inner join alumno_cuatrimestre_materia a on n.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia = a.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia
                              WHERE n.idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia =:alumno AND iddocente_materia =:materia");
        $sql->execute(
            //Aqui van las variables:
            //:materia-> contiene el iddocente_materia de la relacion entre un docente y una materia
            //:alumno-> contiene los id's de los alumnos seleccionados desde la tabla alumno_cuatrimestre_materia.
            array(
                ':materia'       =>  $_POST['materia'],
                ':alumno'        =>  $valor
            )
        );
        $result = $sql->fetchObject();
        //Si la consulta de verificacion recibe un valor > 0 no inserta
        if ($result->total > 0)
        {
            echo 'error, ya existe ';
        }
        else
        {
            //De lo contrario inicia la inserción de registros.
            $query = "INSERT INTO notas (iddocente_materia, idalumno_cuatrimestre_materia)
               VALUES(:materia, :alumno)";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':materia'       =>  $_POST['materia'],
                    ':alumno'        =>  $valor
                )
            );
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();

        }
        if(isset($result))
        {
            echo 'insertado correctamente ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No entendí bien tu problema... en el `data` de la petición Ajax puedes poner los criterios que quieras, sea 1 o sean 100. Luego en el servidor debes saber cómo recibir la petición para saber qué hacer con ella. Incluso en el `data`  tú puedes poner otros tipos de identificadores, para luego buscarlos en PHP y actuar en consecuencia. Por ejemplo: `data= {action : 'insert', data: 'los datos'}` luego en el servidor buscas el valor de `action` y si es `insert` insertas, si es `update` actualizas, si es `delete` borras. Usando lo que hayas enviado en `data`.

Comment: @A.Cedano haciendo un console.log(form_data) antes del $.ajax me manda esto: docente=6&materia=30&alumno=87&alumno=109&hidden_alumno=87%2C109
dependiendo de cuantos alumnos seleccione (en este caso 2), quisiera que también me enviara un valor tipo "idmateria=x" dependiendo el o los alumnos que se seleccionaron para luego guardar ese post en una variable, pero no se como hacer eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya me salio, no se porque me trabe mucho en esa parte, muchas gracias por el ejemplo que pusiste supongo que ilumino o algo por el estilo xD.

Comment: Hola  @Member no tienes que añadir [RESUELTO] al título de la pregunta, debes publicar una respuesta como lo has hecho y marcarla como correcta, creo que si es tu propia respuesta SO solo te permitira marcarla como correcta en 2 días, por lo que espera y en ese momento marcala, asi sabremos que esta resuelto

Comment: Hola @eyllanesc entiendo, y si, tengo que esperar 2 dias para calificarla como respuesta. Gracias por el aviso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como @A.Cenado comento solo le puse un id asignando el `idmateria` de mi consulta en esa parte a las opciones generadas en el `combobox` materias

```
foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option id="'.$row["idmateria"].'" value="'.$row["iddocente_materia"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
        }
```

y agrege otro input oculto despues del input `hidden_alumno`

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_idmateria" id="hidden_idmateria" />
```

despues al momento de enviar por ajax al php solo agrege:

```
$('#hidden_idmateria').val($('#materia option:selected').attr("id"));
```

y con eso ya pude recibir el id de la materia seleccionaba por POST en el php para realizar la validación de la consulta.

No se si sea la manera correcta pero por ahora me funciono.